Can I split excel cells word by word into rows where every cells contains only one word using Python?
i have an excel file with texts in a lot of cells and i want to split these texts word by word and organize into cells in one column by rows. Like every cell contains one word. it is because after i got this organized excel i would like to do a vlookup. is it possible with python?

Yes, it is possible. However your question is too vague, you must provide a [mre].

i tried the following code but never actually worked either keyerror or value error was the result at the end:
words=[]
for col in df.columns:
for cell in df[col]:
if isinstance(cell, str):
words.extend(cell.split())
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
new_df.loc[0] = words
output_file = "output.xlsx"
new_df.to_excel(output_file, index=False, header=False)
output_df = pd.read_excel(output_file, header=None)

Please edit your question instead of adding hard to parse code in comments

You can use pandas library for this
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('input_file.xlsx')  # Replace 'input_file.xlsx' with your actual file name

words = [] # Initialize an empty list to hold the words

# Iterate over each cell in the dataframe, split the text, and append words to the list
for col in df.columns:
    for cell in df[col]:
        if pd.notna(cell):  # Check if the cell is not empty (NaN)
            words.extend(cell.split())

# Create a new DataFrame with each word in a separate row under a single column
words_df = pd.DataFrame(words, columns=['Words'])

words_df.to_excel('output_file.xlsx', index=False)  # Replace 'output_file.xlsx' with the desired output file name

